# Calculating the inverse of the given function:$g(x)=f(x)-2$ in terms of $f^{-1}$

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, elementary-functions

As the title states I have to find the inverse in terms of $f^{-1}$ for $g(x)=f(x)-2$

I'm having a little hard time understanding how treat this function.

I've read few examples here on the math.stackexchange and  there it's solved by treating it as a composite.

However, the author of this book did abstain from using composites which leads me believe that it's possible without, even though it might be more difficult.

Anyhow, in the formula the author gets the answer:

$f(y)=x+2$ and $g^{−1}(x) = y = f^{−1}(x + 2)$

I would very much appreciate it if somebody could provide some insight.

Comment: What about the given solution are you having difficulty with? It is fairly straight-forward.

Comment: I get how they obtain $f(y)=x+2$, but what does this equate to? Is this the inverse for $g(x)$ which is equal to $y$? if so I might then understand. But the extra function bewilders me a little.

Comment: They take $f^{-1}$ to both sides, and $f^{-1}(f(y))=y$, where $y=g^{-1}(x)$. (The standard technique of switching $x$ and $y$ and solving for $y$.)

Answer (score 2):

$$g(x) = f(x) - 2$$
Thus, subbing in $g^{-1}(x)$ for $x$,
$$g(g^{-1}(x)) = x = f(g^{-1}(x)) - 2 \implies f(g^{-1}(x)) = x + 2$$
so, composing this with $f^{-1}$,
$$f^{-1}(f(g^{-1}(x))) = g^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(x+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Try to solve

$$y = f(x)-2,$$

that is express $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: and I get $f(y)=x+2$. I think i'm mostly confused by what it should equate to.

since $g(x)=y=f(x)-2$ 

is $g^{-1}(x)=x+2$ then?

Comment: Let's go slower, try to express $f(x)$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: for $y=f(x)-2$  in terms of y I get $f(x)=y+2$

Comment: Awesome, now to solve for $x$, $f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(y+2)$, and you have found the inverse.

Comment: Sorry for the delay between your respons and this one. So I've pondered a little. Since I want to express this in terms of $f^{-1}$. I would want to find the inverse for $g(x)$ which would equal $y+2$ in this case. Understanding that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$(cancellation indentity) I would simply have to take the inverse of the inverse ( $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x))$) to obtain $y+2$.I just want to confirm with you if you think I somewhat grasp the intuition behind this problem.

Thank you btw for your help!

Comment: the sentence about inverse of $g(x)$ is $y+2$ is cryptic to me.

Comment: My apologies. I was thinking that because $g(x)=y=f(x)-2$:

$y=f(x)-2$. By employing the standard technique for taking the inverse by switching x and y we would get: $f(y)=x+2$ which would be the inverse $g^{-1}(x)$, right? I hope this atleast clears things up regarding my train of thought.

Comment: ok, we have obtain $f(y)=x+2$, one more step away is to apply $f^{-1}$ on both sides, $y=f^{-1}(x+2)$ which is $g^{-1}(x)$.